# Do user ID's with periods break jquery-socialist?

Tags: jquery

I am experimenting with the `jquery-socialist plugin` and the code functions as expected when using the ID's in the examples featured [here](http://plugins.in1.com/socialist).

That said, I seem to be experiencing failures, specifically when attempting to connect to a Facebook user whose ID contains a period `.` in the username.  Has anyone encountered this issue or successfully retrieved data via jquery-socialist from Facebook using an ID that contains special characters?